# Null Exception in File Uploading in MVC4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created the following view, with having file upload and submit button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home",
                    FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

I have also created the action method in Controller but **it gives the null at the "uploadFile"**

```
[HttpPost)]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {
            if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                               Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
                uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `uploadFile` isn't null when the method is called?

Comment: yes. uploadFile has file at the time when method was called.

Comment: Can you just humour me and put an identical `id` attribute on the upload? E.g: `<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />`?

Comment: Not working, <input name="uploadFile" type="file" id="uploadFile" />

Comment: Can you debug and check `Request.Files` actually has entries? If it doesn't.. your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Where I found the Request.Files. I have not use this  in my code

Comment: @BhupendraShukla [See the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019345/null-exception-in-file-uploading-in-mvc4-razor/19019855#19019855)

Comment: @BhupendraShukla Are you sure your form is getting submitted? without any server exceptions?

Comment: No server exception, even no warning at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can u try `Name` with same as `uploadFile`

**In your Page:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home",
                    FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

As per @Willian Duarte comment : `[HttpPost]`

**In your Code behind:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile) // OR IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadFile
{
    //For checking purpose 
     HttpPostedFileBase File = Request.Files["uploadFile"];

    if (File != null)
    {
        //If this is True, then its Working.,
    }

    if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                       Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
        uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
    return View();
}
```

[See here Same question like yours.,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051052/file-is-not-posted-to-actionresult-how-to-upload-files-on-mvc-c/18051469#18051469)

[Code project Article about the File upload.,](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79043/An-Example-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-Project-to-Upload-and-D)

Comment: @BhupendraShukla [Lets continue our discussion here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28436/c-developers)

Comment: have you tried instead of `HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile` to `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadFile` as i mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually there is also no problem in my code, the error is produced due to wrong reference of Helper method i created earlier. Now my code is also running fine.

Comment: Setting the id and name worked for me.  Only setting the id did not work for me.

Comment: @Wonderboy The `file control name` should be same as `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter name in Controller Action Result. It will work like View Model Concept. Ex : Creating property for the control and getting the value in Controller from View.

Comment: @Wonderboy set the name and check it will work., :) I have edited my answer., Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

create a model and bind it to your view that controller will also expect:

**Controller:**

```
    //Model (for instance I've created it inside controller, you can place it in model
    public class uploadFile
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase file{ get; set; }
    }

    //Action
    public ActionResult Index(uploadFile uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.file.FileName));
            uploadFile.file.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**View**
    @model sampleMVCApp.Controllers.HomeController.uploadFile

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home",
                FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file"});  
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

Tested Solution!

HTH :)

Comment: Why would you suggest going backwards? This is 2013.. we don't need to access a `FormCollection`..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: thanks for the suggestion, edited my answer, now it should work :)

Comment: @BhupendraShukla: check my answer now, tested.

Comment: plz mark it as answer then, so that other would get it in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use (on controller):

```
var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
```

Comment: For asp.net mvc 4 you can use [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] instead [AcceptVerbs..]

Comment: I tried both [HttpPost] and [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] but i think that is not an issue. Currently using [HttpPost].

I tried your code but it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in the controller:

```
var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
```

Use HttpPost instead of [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]