# Get file names from multiple files uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have `4 fileupload` in my form. I want when I click a button, I get the file name and set to model, then the file upload to server. But i don't want must use 4 file, I can use 3, 2, or 1 file upload at a time by choice. If I only use 2 file upload, file3 and file4 model still null. what I must do in my controller ?

Any ideas or suggestion?

**Model:**

```
public string file1 {get;set;}
public string file2 {get;set;}
public string file3 {get;set;}
public string file4 {get;set;}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file3" />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file4" />

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson thanks for reply,its only model and view, I don't know what I should do in My controller, any ideas ?

Comment: Have you looked at any existing questions?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0

Comment: @JustinHelgerson thanks justin, I can if only use 1 file upload, how about use multiple fileupload and use IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> like this http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/. I cannot get the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***In Your View :***

***Note:*** *Here your model names are not required. Through action result parameter you going to pass your files.*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home",
                    FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
    <input type="file" name="file4" id="file4" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

***In your Controller:***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file1, HttpPostedFileBase file2, HttpPostedFileBase file3, HttpPostedFileBase file4) // OR IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file1 = Request.Files["file1"];
    HttpPostedFileBase file2 = Request.Files["file2"];    
    HttpPostedFileBase file3 = Request.Files["file3"];
    HttpPostedFileBase file4 = Request.Files["file4"];

    if (file1 != null) // Same for file2, file3, file4
    {
        //If this is True, then file1 has file.,
    }

    // Check and Save the file1 // Same for file2, file3, file4
    if (file1.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
                                       Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
        uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
    }

    return View();
}
```

*There is an article about file uploading in [Codeproject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019345/null-exception-in-file-uploading-in-mvc4-razor/19019855#19019855)
I didn't checked the above code. Let me know if that is not getting worked.*

Comment: yes its work, thanks you, but its work if different name fileupload, can you give me example with same name fileupload like this http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Comment: yes, multiple file upload but same name fileupload and use IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>, I think if use it, I don't need repeat the code

Comment: Try Like this : `<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="file3" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="file4" />` and keep action result  `public ActionResult FileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {  // Your Operations Here return View(); }`

Comment: @RJK This is exactly what I needed thank you for the clear instructions.